# Django 1.3.1 model form clean method

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.2.x works fine with these but problem exist in Django 1.3.1 because I have validation error which say that selected option is not in the list.
I have model form

model:

```
class Cvet(models.Model):
    ...
    template = models.ForeignKey(Predefinisan_tekst, blank=True, null=True, related_name='template')
    ...
```

form:

```
class NoviCvetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cvet

    def clean(self):
        super(NoviCvetForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        template = cleaned_data.get("template")
        if template == '------':
            cleaned_data["template"] = None
        return cleaned_data
```

Now in django template `template` is select field and i have manually created `<option selected="selected">------</option>` as a first option in list. Because of that, when form is submited without user choice in this field, `request.POST` send value of `template` field as `------` which is not valid option. What I need to change in `clean` method to get value of that field as none?

Comment: That looks fine to me - are you sure you have (a) restarted the server (b) got the exact right value for your check? Also, it might be worth checking if there is a difference if you don't call the superclass version of clean.

Comment: I'm try also without `super(NoviCvetForm, self).clean()` but result is the same. And yes server is restarted and value is `------`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `None` isn't a value in the list. I'm not sure how you got this to work with a previous version of Django, because the problem would have been the same there. Nevertheless, you must store a valid value (from `choices`) in the `cleaned_data` array or it won't pass validation ever.

If you want to actually store `None` when `-----` is selected, then override the `save` method for that.